# launch different activity?

Tags: android-activity

Can we launch the Angry Birds game by button click in some Activity?
I am able to launch reader activity by  button click in my Activity.
And I know that we can launch the activity from one package to another package.
The code is as follows for angry birds and reader
I am able to launch the reader and I don't why I am not able to launch the angry birds?

Code for Angry Birds is as follows..

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.rovio.angrybirds","com.rovio.ka3d.app");
            intent.setComponent(cn);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Code for Book redear is as follows..

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.bluefirereader","com.bluefirereader.BookActivity");
            intent.setComponent(cn);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

please help me..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution.Actually the code which I used earlier is correct.And the thing is Component info what I am giving to Intent is wrong.
The Code is as follows....

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.rovio.angrybirds","com.rovio.ka3d.App");//Here erlier I put com.rovio.ka3d.app instead of com.rovio.ka3d.App
        intent.setComponent(cn);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```